# Apache2.service failed to start

Tags: server, permissions, apache2

I have a brand new to Linux/Ubuntu Server. I'm just trying to get a Virtual Host setup but my apache2 package will not start. I keep getting the same failure messages like:

Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server

then I'll type `systemctl status apache2.service` and it reads (picking out particulars):

- `Active: failed (Result: exit-code)` since Sat 2016-07-30 ...etc.
- Docs:  `man:systems-sysv-generator(8)`
- `Process: 4832 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)`
- (*) The apache2 `configtest` failed. Output of config test was: `AH00526: Syntax error on line 22 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-deault.conf`
- `Cannot find module ssl Action 'configtest' failed`. The Apache error
  log may have more information.

and this is where I get frustrated. I then try to access the error log and

No.1 It kept denying me permissions so I played with some `sudo` and permissions stuff and finally got that to go away but now,

No.2 I have no clue how to read the error log file. Nano brings up nothing, `tail -f` brings up endless nothing, typing simply `/var/log/apache2/error.log` does nothing.... I'm stuck.

Comment: The error message "Cannot find module ssl" points to the cause of the problem, are you certain that you enabled it correctly using the "sudo a2enmod ssl" command? If that doesn't help then it might be useful to add the contents of your /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.load and /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf files to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much @MttJocy. Could I ask you to point me to some good resources where I can learn more about Apache2 web servers?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @mttjocy, enabling SSL module for `Apache` fixed it for me.

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
```